# Files.ubuntu recovery

Tags: files, data-recovery

Hae. Is it possible for one to access/recover files that were backed up with https://files.one.ubuntu.com/ and if it's possible kindly give me a guide to how I can achieve that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Host files.one.ubuntu.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

Comment: No, that link is not valid. And you use a backup system that you do not know how to restore from before you use it? Seems a bit odd to me.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu One closed down long ago.

https://ubuntu.com/blog/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services

> 2 April 2014
>
> Today we are announcing plans to shut down the Ubuntu One file services.  This is a tough decision, particularly when our users rely so heavily on the functionality that Ubuntu One provides.  However, like any company, we want to focus our efforts on our most important strategic initiatives and ensure we are not spread too thin.
>
> ..
>
> Customers who have an active annual subscription will have their unused fees refunded. We will calculate the refund amount from today’s announcement, even though the service will remain available until 1 June and data available for a further two months.

Any backup done whilst Ubuntu One offered file-services will be too stale today I bet, though as those files no longer exist it doesn't matter.

Ubuntu One does still exist, providing SSO & other services, but **not** file-services.